# Sinon delay callback function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I simply want to simulate delayed callback function. I am using sinon and mocha for testing. I changed readFile of standart fs library. I want the `yields` function to be executed after 5 seconds. Thus, the callback function will run after 5 seconds. But It didnt work. It worked when I run the `yields` function before the `fs.readFile` function.

```
function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}

it.only('test stıb',  async () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile');
    stub.withArgs('path', 'utf8');

    fs.readFile("path", "utf8", (err, data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
    await sleep(5000);
    stub.yields(null, "Read File Message");
    stub.restore();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It just seems like order of operations issue in your test.

`.yields` to to set up the behavior of your stub. Mocking after you already called the function you are trying to test is backwards.

```
function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}

it.only('test stıb',  async () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(fs, 'readFile');
    stub.withArgs('path', 'utf8');
    stub.yields(null, "Read File Message");

    await sleep(5000);

    fs.readFile("path", "utf8", (err, data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    stub.restore();
});
```

Comment: Actually exactly what I want, The callback function should run 5 seconds after calling the ReadFile function. So I wanted to simulate heavy operations in the readFile function.